# Complex Analysis Integration involving log and branch cut

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{\log(z)\ dz}{(z-1)^2(z-1+3i)}$$

where $\gamma$ encloses the branch cut of $\log(z)$ in counter-clockwise direction with infinitesimal distance, starting at $-\infty+i\epsilon$ and ending at $-\infty+i\epsilon$.

So i'm not quite sure about what to do about the branch cut.

Proceed as normal we would first notice the two singularities at $z=1$ and $z=1-3i$. Normally the log function would have a branch cut along the negative real axis. But i assume i need one of these singularities to be enclosed by this contour? It seems i'd have to assume that $z=1$ is enclosed within this contour? Then i'd simply proceed with residue theorem to calculate the value of the integral.

In this case:

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=1}=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{d}{dz}{(z-1)^2f(z)}=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{\log(z)}{z-1+3i}\right)=-\frac{i}{3}$$

So the integral would be $$\int_Cf(z)dz=2\pi i\left(-\frac{i}{3}\right)=\frac{2\pi}{3}$$

I am guessing and assuming lots of things here, would appreciate if someone could clear things up!

Many thanks.

Comment: What contour is $\gamma$?

Comment: Is [this contour](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oh5oyzw2p9) what you have in mind as $C$? I didn't take the poles into consideration yet, BTW.

Comment: @Accelerator yes this is the contour i had in mind

Comment: I see. Are you defining $\gamma$ to be the two line segments then? Those line segments are two separate contours.

Answer (score 0):

You will firstly need the contour to be closed to apply the residue theorem.

> where $\gamma$
> encloses the branch cut of $log(z)$
> in counter-clockwise direction with infinitesimal distance, starting at $−∞+iϵ$
> and ending at $−∞+iϵ$.

I assume that you meant starting at $-\infty-i\epsilon$ and ending at $-\infty+i\epsilon$, so that the countour is indeed counter-clockwise?

To enclose the countour, let the integrated function go around a sufficiently big circle, i.e., $Re^{i\theta}$, $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$, and $R$ sufficiently large.

Note that $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$: the branch cut of the $log$ function is at the negative axis!! That is, the imaginary part of the $log$ function must lie within the range of $\theta$ too.

Now that observe the integral is $0$ on the big circle, we can finally apply the residue theorem. Note that we have a clockwise rotation on the big circle, actually $-2\pi i \: Res$ is the result.

Now that you can calculate the Residues and obtain the integral :)

Comment: How does a contour start at $-\infty - i\epsilon$ and end at $-\infty + i\epsilon$?

Comment: could you go a bit into more detail, im not sure i understood